# initstate vs initstate_r: confusing arguments

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to make sense of the manpage for `initstate` and `initstate_r`. Both functions are initializing the random generator. `initstate` should not be used if you have multiple threads but for that scenario you should use `initstate_r`.

The signature of these functions are

```
char *initstate(unsigned int seed, char *state, size_t n);
int initstate_r(unsigned int seed, char *statebuf,
                size_t statelen, struct random_data *buf);
```

and the descripiton of the manpages say

```
   The initstate() function allows a state array state to be initialized  for  use  by  random().
   The size of the state array n is used by initstate() to decide how sophisticated a random num‐
   ber generator it should use—the larger the state array, the better the random numbers will be.
   seed  is the seed for the initialization, which specifies a starting point for the random num‐
   ber sequence, and provides for restarting at the same point.

   The  initstate_r()  function  is like initstate(3) except that it initializes the state in the
   object pointed to by buf, rather than initializing the global state variable.
```

What I do not understand is why there are two arguments that are holding the state of the random generator in the case of `initstate_r`: `statebuf` and `buf`. If even `initstate` has an argument `state` that holds the state of the random number generator, why do you need an additional parameter for `initrand_r` at all? Shouldn't they just hold the same information?

And must both, `statebuf` and `buf` be thread-local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both must be thread local.

As to why you need both, well, it's a (imho poorly thought) design choice.
They **could** (should?) have hidden the state inside random_data, especially since random_data has to be big enough to hold the state for srandom_r (ie a buffer with size=128).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int32_t i32;
        struct random_data r;
        srandom_r(1, &r);
        random_r(&r, &i32);
        return i32;
}
```

Except that the above segfaults (even if you zero the `r` vaiable first): by reading https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=stdlib/random_r.c;hb=656b84c2ef525e3b69802c9057c5897e327b0332 it looks like they expect you to provide storage for the random array, ie srandom() picks a default size of 128, srandom_r expects you to have provided space for the state array.

The rationale, I guess, is that the state array can be "big" (max 256 bytes), so they won't be allocating potentially wasted space (some people bother keeping a small stack size for their threads).

About the difference between `statebuf` and `buf`: `statebuf` holds the information you need for random_r, ie the state array and its metadata (size, whatever) in a packed format (opaque, traditionally squeezed in `statebuf[0]` - eg: 1st byte=size, 2nd byte=...), while `buf` is the "unpacked" version of `statebuf`, so it's more convenient for implementing random_r.

I see this is turning more into a rant than an answer - let me know if anything is particularly incomprehensible :)